# session not unset in codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i can working with multilanguage site and also working this site but one problrm when switch another language that language set in session but next time automatic detect session if session not set so default language set and that store in session that working  but when switch language that language not set in session

how i can fix this problem

```
  if(empty($CI->session->userdata('languagename')))
    {
        echo "yes session is empty";
    }
    else 
    {
        $CI->session->unset_userdata('languagename');
        echo "yes session is Not empty";
    }

   // $CI->session->unset_userdata('languagename');
    $data=array(
            'languagename'=> $lang
    );
    $CI->session->set_userdata($data);
```

this is my code

[This GitHub Core class used](https://github.com/waqleh/codeigniter-language-in-url-internationalization)

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: change empty to !isset and try it..let me know then

Comment: already try it bro this also not working :(

Comment: ! isse t<--- did you add ! or not

Comment: before empty adding  but give warning

Comment: chagne `if(empty($CI->session->userdata('languagename')))` to  `if(!isset($CI->session->userdata('languagename')))`

Comment: Ok aagin try it your code bro :)

Comment: error see ==>  http://i.stack.imgur.com/6bAQq.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121310/discussion-between-hothi-jimit-and-danyal-sandeelo).

Answer (score 1):

Try this way in your logout function

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session');      
$CI->session->sess_destroy();
```

this might solve your problem
i suppose you are writing this code in your library file

Comment: i donot want login session destroy only language session remove :P